# On existence of Singular value decomposition in von Neumann algebras

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

For which class of von Neumann algebras we will have singular value decomposition of each element of the algebra?

Comment: You would have to define what you mean by "singular value decomposition".

Comment: @MartinArgerami for matrix algebras if we take any matrix $A$  there is orthogonal matrices $U$ and $V$ such that $A=UDV$ where D is diagonal matrices containing the eigenvalues of $|A|$ with decreasing order. The proof comes from polar decomposition.

Comment: The question of Martin is pertinent. It is not clear (to me) what do you want your diagonal algebra to be in a general von Neumann algebra. If you pick a generic Abelian subalgebra $D$ you would need that any selfadjoint element $x  \in M$ lies in $U^\ast  D U$ or some unitary. Therefore, a natural condition would be that all unital Abelian subalgebras are conjugate.

Comment: @Adrian can you give a nontrivial example such that all unital abelian subalgebras are unitary conjugate?

Comment: I forgot the word "maximal".

Comment: Beside finite dimensional algebras I cannot give an example from the top of my head. I think that there are nonequivalent maximal Abelian subalgebras (MASA's) in the hyperfinite II$_1$ factor: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0602155.pdf

Comment: There are non-equivalent masas in $B(H)$, namely the discrete and continuous masas.